# Firedac -Como usar mesma FDquery em mais de um banco?

Tags: delphi, firedac

ouvi falar que o FD tem como programar para dois gerenciadores de bancos de dados diferentes usando mesmas `FDQuery`, isto é, daria pra colocar os dois SQL´s de cada banco no mesmo `FDQuery`... ou coisa assim...

Aguem tem algum tutorial para isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olá, sim é possível. O componente a ser usado é `FDLocalSQL`, onde você basicamente faria o `SELECT` de uma `FDQuery`.
Na prática, funciona assim:

1. Insira um componente `FDLocalSQL`;
2. Insira os dataset´s ligados aos N bancos que você queira, cada um
   com seus devidos SQL´s;
3. Ligue a propriedade `LocalSQL` de cada dataset no componente `FDLocalSQl`;
4. Insira um novo `FDConnection` com o Driver `SQLite`;
5. Insira uma nova `FDQuery` no formulário;
6. Ligue o `FDLocalSQL` e a nova Query no `FDConnection` do item 4.0;
7. Nesse último `FDQuery`, insira o SQL referenciando a cada Query como
   sendo uma tabela.
   Ex.: `SELECT NOME FROM FDQUERY1 JOIN FDQUERY2 ON (FDQUERY1.CAMPO = FDQUERY2.CAMPO)`;
8. Abra o último dataset.