# Delphi - Unir duas tabelas de bancos de dados diferentes

Tags: delphi, firebird, delphi-xe4, paradox

Tenho um banco de dados Firebird (F) com os dados de profissionais:

```
Nome, Idade, CBO
```

Tenho uma tabela Paradox (P) com os dados de ocupações:

```
CBO, Descrição
```

O que quero fazer é unir essas duas tabelas de forma que fique:

```
Nome, Idade, CBO, Descrição
```

onde `F.CBO = P.CBO`

é possível?

Comment: Sim, é possível com uma técnica chamada dblink. Pesquisa um pouco sobre esse tema, e pergunte-nos se tiver alguma duvida.

Comment: obrigado, irei pesquisar sim. toda ajuda é válida

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível por meio do `FireDAC`, biblioteca de acesso a dados.
Veja a [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/160545/49822) que forneci, muito interessante e fácil.

Comment: obrigado, irei fazer o que me indicou